# DateTime culture issue in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, datetime, culture

I use Entity Framework with a code-first approach to send a model to database (which is SQL Server 2014).

The model has 2 DateTime fields and one of them is user input. I store it in a `datetime?` variable and then EF does the rest to store the model in the database.

My project is multi culture and when I am using another culture like `fa-ir`, then EF shows the following error :

> The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value. The statement has been terminated.

It works in windows 2014 and newer which have Persian culture but not in previous versions which didn't support Persian culture.

Any solution?

Comment: you can change culture of threa to persian ..before inserrting vlaue

Comment: @pranay-rana  yes i changed the culture to en-us and the problem didn't get solved!

Comment: Ok , I tried that trick in my code of ado.net and it worked for me so thats y i suggested

Comment: You have to choose one calendar (persian or gregorian) and prefferably one timezone (UTC) and store all dates in that format in your database. Storing them all in different timezones and even calendars won't do anything good.

Comment: Please show us the code being executed when the exception occurs. Be sure to highlight the line that throws the exception

Comment: Why did you just delete you other question? You got it to an answerable state.

Answer (score 1):

SQL `datetime` data type only supports dates from 1753-01-01 to 9999-12-31.

But current year in persian calendar is 1396.

So you have to change the SQL column to [`datetime2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql) data type which supports 0001-01-01 to 9999-12-31.

Comment: i select a date in this range and it is stored in a datetime variable . i want to store the date in database in datetime format because the result is in this range.it is not the reason for this error and besides that i don't like workarounds and temporary solutions!